# user data directory in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-source

User data in android 4.2 onwards is stored at `/data/user/<userId>`

But still I found `/data/data` directory in android 4.3 filesystem. I think it is there to store application data that is common for all users and `/data/user/<userId>` is used for storing user specific application data. Is this true?

Comment: On Tablet or Device???

Comment: emulator(tablet) and mobile device

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

`/data/data` always belongs to the primary user. You can see this by listing `/data/user` directory:

`/data/user/0` is a soft-link to `/data/data` and the permissions are set so that only this "user 0" has access to all the data stored in `/data/data`.

Therefore `/data/data` is not common for all users.