# SQLite Database found in different directory

Tags: android, sqlite

Generally SQLite database is locate in **`/data/data/PACKAGE-NAME/databases/DBNAME`** but I found database in **`/data/user/0/PACKAGE-NAME/databases/DBNAME`** path in one device.

So, why this happened in single device?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464495/user-data-directory-in-android-4-3

Comment: @shizhen and mesutpiskin I checked in emulator now, it contains database in both directory- **data/data/... & data/user/0/...**. So which one I have to use?

Comment: In some devices, `/data/data` is a symbolic link to `/data/user/0` or reverse in some devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should programatically get the database **file** path rather than use a hardcoded manner. See API doc for [getDatabasePath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) ; E.g.

```
// for `Activity`, `Service`. Otherwise simply get the context.
Context context = this;
String dbname = "dummy.db";
String dbpath = context.getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath();
Log.d("MY_TAG", dbpath);
```

[image]

If you want to get the database **folder** path, use `getParent()` like below:

```
String databaseFolderPath = context.getDatabasePath(dbname).getParent();
```