# Invalid path using path_provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, path

I am new to Flutter and development. When I checking and playing around with path_provider, I have stored some files in the emulator. When I print the path it shows **/data/user/0/package_name/app_flutter/filename**. When I search using Device File explorer I can't find anything like that but found **/data/data/package_name/app_flutter/filename**. Why it shows /user/0/ than /data/data/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device

Comment: No, I am just asking why path provider gives /data/user/0/path rather than /data/data/package_name?

Comment: Ah, then a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468415/8673915). They are the same directory.